# Issue Avoiding Js Alert in Cefsharp browser

Tags: c#, chromium, cefsharp

I am trying to avoid js alert on a page as it breaks the flow and the browser is stuck on that page until the popup is clicked.

I added Class as shown on sample:

```
public class JsDialogHandler : IJsDialogHandler
{
    public bool OnJSDialog(IWebBrowser browserControl, IBrowser browser, string originUrl, CefJsDialogType dialogType, string messageText, string defaultPromptText, IJsDialogCallback callback, ref bool suppressMessage)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public bool OnJSBeforeUnload(IWebBrowser browserControl, IBrowser browser, string message, bool isReload, IJsDialogCallback callback)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public void OnResetDialogState(IWebBrowser browserControl, IBrowser browser)
    {

    }

    public void OnDialogClosed(IWebBrowser browserControl, IBrowser browser)
    {

    }
}
```

And i assign to the Chromium browser as:

```
  CefSharp.Cef.Initialize(new CefSharp.CefSettings());

                browser = new CefSharp.WinForms.ChromiumWebBrowser(CustomLinks[0].ToString());

                JsDialogHandler jss = new JsDialogHandler();
                browser.JsDialogHandler = jss;
```

The thing is when alert is supposed to show it does run the `OnJSDialog` event. But then the browser turns white and is just stuck and trying to find a way around but not much is available online..

Any suggestions?

Comment: You need to execute the `callback`, read the `xml doc` for instructions.

Comment: @amaitland can you please post link for that.

Comment: Just navigate to the method in visual studio and read the documentation

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the `OnJSDialog` method of your handler, make sure that you call `Continue(...)` on the callback:

```
public bool OnJSDialog(IWebBrowser browserControl, IBrowser browser, string originUrl, CefJsDialogType dialogType, string messageText, string defaultPromptText, IJsDialogCallback callback, ref bool suppressMessage) {
  callback.Continue(true);
  return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you simply want to disable javascript alerts, there is parameter `suppressMessage` just for that:

```
// Implementation of IJsDialogHandler
public bool OnJSDialog(IWebBrowser browserControl, IBrowser browser, string originUrl, CefJsDialogType dialogType, string messageText, string defaultPromptText, IJsDialogCallback callback, ref bool suppressMessage)
{
    suppressMessage = true;
    return false;
}
// All other methods should do nothing or return false.
```

Comment: The best answer IMO.